# Как загрузить и использовать веса сохраненной модели?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, tensorflow, keras

Проблема заключается в том, что я без понятия, как загрузить веса сохраненной модели и использовать их. Читал документацию, но ни один из способов не подошел. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
import os
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'


class DenseNN(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, outputs, activate="relu"):
        super().__init__()
        self.outputs = outputs
        self.activate = activate
        self.fl_init = False

    def __call__(self, x):
        if not self.fl_init:
            self.w = tf.random.truncated_normal((x.shape[-1], self.outputs), stddev=0.1, name="w")
            self.b = tf.zeros([self.outputs], dtype=tf.float32, name="b")

            self.w = tf.Variable(self.w)
            self.b = tf.Variable(self.b)

            self.fl_init = True

        y = x @ self.w + self.b

        if self.activate == "relu":
            return tf.nn.relu(y)
        elif self.activate == "softmax":
            return tf.nn.softmax(y)

        return y


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train / 255
x_test = x_test / 255

x_train = tf.reshape(tf.cast(x_train, tf.float32), [-1, 28 * 28])
x_test = tf.reshape(tf.cast(x_test, tf.float32), [-1, 28 * 28])

y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 10)

layer_1 = DenseNN(128)
layer_2 = DenseNN(10, activate="softmax")

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layer_1)
model.add(layer_2)


def model_predict(x):
    y = layer_1(x)
    y = layer_2(y)
    return y  # layer_2(layer_1(x))


cross_entropy = lambda y_true, y_pred: tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred))
opt = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

BATCH_SIZE = 32
EPOCHS = 10
TOTAL = x_train.shape[0]

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

for n in range(EPOCHS):
    loss = 0

    for x_batch, y_batch in train_dataset:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            f_loss = cross_entropy(y_batch, model_predict(x_batch))

        loss += f_loss
        grads = tape.gradient(f_loss, [layer_1.trainable_variables, layer_2.trainable_variables])
        opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads[0], layer_1.trainable_variables))
        opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads[1], layer_2.trainable_variables))

    print(loss.numpy())

y = model_predict(x_test)
y2 = tf.argmax(y, axis=1).numpy()
acc = len(y_test[y_test == y2]) / y_test.shape[0] * 100
print(acc)

y = model_predict(tf.expand_dims(x_test[0], axis=0))
print(y)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)
model.save_weights('model_weights.h5')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А в каком смысле не подошли способы, что происходило?

Comment: У меня просто не получалось загрузить веса сохраненной модели, а как их использовать в дальнейшем, вообще без понятия

Comment: Загрузка весов нужна вместо model.fit, чтобы на тренировку время не тратить

Comment: Вот проблема в том , что я не знаю как их загрузить

Comment: https://tensorflow.google.cn/guide/keras/save_and_serialize

Comment: `model = keras.models.load_model('model_weights.h5n')`

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю (и как сам обычно это делаю), для сохранения ML моделей можно использовать, например, библиотеку `pickle`
Здесь (https://russianblogs.com/article/45551380910/) доступно и с примерами кода объясняют, как именно это можно сделать (хотя перевели статью так себе).

Надеюсь, сработает!